# XAMPP not turning off

Tags: xampp

I have XAMPP already installed on my Windows and I'm trying to turn it off so I can use IIS "which looks like a movie by itself". The problem is that XAMPP is refusing to turn off and is giving me a busy error:

> Busy...
>
> ERROR -1

The error message is really inexpressive so I have no idea what the problem could be. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is really simple (and stupid). I only needed to run XAMPP with administrative access, that's all.